# Match two data frames in R considering two variables and not change the rows not matched

Tags: r, join, dataframe

Hi everybody I have a little problem matching two data frames in R when they have two common variables to be matched. The first data frame is like this:

```
Class  Count  V1  V2 V3
E       124   1   2   2
E       123   2   0   0
L       100   5   5   5
L       111   1   1   1
E       120   3   3   3
```

Second data frame has this form:

```
Class  Count Code
E       124  1241
L       111  1234
```

I would like to have a new data frame considering `Class` and `Count` variables for the match. The resulting data frame would be like this:

```
    Class  Count   V1    V2 V3
    E       124   1241   2   2
    E       123   2      0   0
    L       100   5      5   5
    L       111   1234   1   1
    E       120   3      3   3
```

Where only the elements that have matched were replaced with `Code` variable in `V1` variable. The rest of elements are the same and I don't have `NA` and other changes in my first data frame. I wait it is possible to make in R. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please `dput` the data

Comment: There are a few examples in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 df1$V1<-ifelse((df1$Class==df2$Class & df1$Count==df2$Count),df2$Code,df1$V1)
     df1
  Class Count   V1 V2 V3
1     E   124 1241  2  2
2     E   123    2  0  0
3     L   100    5  5  5
4     L   111 1234  1  1
5     E   120    3  3  3
```

**Updated as per the data provided in comments:**

You can create an interaction variable (int) from c9 and CC4 using `interaction` in both data and then use `%in%` (it seems that you are not looking for row to row match, so you should avoid using `ifelse`). I suggest you to deal with NA in `c9` and `CC4` before using `interaction` .This is because if one of these is NA then value of int will be NA which you may not want for matching (In the following example, I haven't dealt with NA's).

```
df1$int<-interaction(df1$c9,df1$CC4) #z data is df1 and z1 data is df2
df2$int<-interaction(df2$c9,df2$CC4)
df1[df1$int %in% df2$int,5]<-df2[df2$int %in% df1$int,13] #this will replaces col5 of df1 with col13 of df2 if matches occurs otherwise the value of col5 of df1 will be same as before
```

Output:

```
       > df1
         c1  c2 c9 CC4  A.la.vista Montoxv_a120d Montoxv_a15d Montoxv_a186d Montoxv_a30d Montoxv_a60d Montoxv_a7d Montoxv_a90d   int
1  20130830 192  E 111 39324363.19             0          0.0           0.0            0            0     1550000            0 E.111
2  20130830 192  E 124 71061061.04             0          0.0    69608583.8      1452477            0           0            0 E.124
3  20130830 192  E 131        0.00             0     182694.0           0.0      1027283      3308932     2010328      3809021 E.131
4  20130830 192  E 201 66310498.77             0          0.0           0.0            0            0           0            0 E.201
5  20130830 192  E 202        0.00      34403130   10275256.6    40375044.8     17999369     37156810     8953196     32639408 E.202
6  20130830 192  E 203 51885967.69             0          0.0           0.0            0            0           0            0 E.203
7  20130830 192  E 211  3537648.29             0          0.0           0.0            0            0           0            0 E.211
8  20130830 192  E  NA          NA       8181927     314120.5    10816365.6      3295626     11992733     3025800      4673335  <NA>
9  20130830 192  L 101    64013.84             0          0.0           0.0            0            0           0            0 L.101
10 20130830 192  L 111  5429375.87       5000000          0.0           0.0     11000000      8500000     7500000      9900000 L.111
11 20130830 192  L 121  8869286.40             0          0.0     7874386.4            0       994900           0            0 L.121
12 20130830 192  L 123  8805450.00       2200000          0.0     2005700.0      1299000      1300750           0      2000000 L.123
13 20130830 192  L 124  5408668.05             0          0.0     5408668.0            0            0           0            0 L.124
14 20130830 192  L 131        0.00             0    2539885.0           0.0            0      8498099      694912      3793809 L.131
15 20130830 192  L 141 18150400.00             0          0.0    15510400.0      1000000       150000           0      1490000 L.141
16 20130830 192  L 201  4545930.38             0          0.0           0.0            0            0           0            0 L.201
17 20130830 192  L 202        0.00             0          0.0      510609.7            0      1187226           0        95000 L.202
18 20130830 192  L 203   708863.95             0          0.0           0.0            0            0           0            0 L.203
```

To see which row of df1 matches use

```
> which(df1$int %in% df2$int)
[1]  2  6 11 12 13 15 18
```

Comment: It doesn't work for a similar data frame @Metrics I got a message like this `Warning message:
In z$c9 == z1$c9 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: You can ignore the warning message and just type `df1` in the console to see the output.

Comment: But I don't know if your solution depends of the position of rows. I made the same for a similar data frame and there in not a match

Comment: Can you elaborate that ?

Comment: Can I send you the data frames to analyse it I dont get the match, could you give me an email

Comment: Please just `dput` the sample data here or in R public chat.

Comment: My data are avalaible in the next link @Metrics https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3p29q1f9aynqyi/Data.RData?n=83787253

Comment: I don't know what your solution don't give a result

Comment: Ok first file is alocated in this link like z https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83787253/z.txt and second file is z1 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83787253/z1.txt My problem is I want to match `c9` and `CC4` columns in both files and show `Total` variable from from z1 file in `A la vista` column from z file only for matched elements. I don't know what is the problem @Metrics

Comment: Thanks @Metrics I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Thanks @Metrics and is possible for all matched elements in the first data frame, replace the rest of the rows with zero, can I include this in the code that you show or I have to make another process

Comment: Your soluition was awesome @Metrics

Comment: @ Duck: It is possible to assign 0 to nonmatched rows (if I understood your question correctly) 
`df1[!(df1$int %in% df2$int),5]<-0` should work.

Comment: I will test this about zero later but thanks a lot of Awesome crack in R

Comment: I want to assign 0 to matched rows for the rest of elements in the same row, in the case of `E 124` the variable `A la vista` would have the matched value and the rest variables for that row would be 0 @Metrics

Comment: That is I wish to make in my data frame only for matched rows @Metrics

Comment: `df1[df1$int %in% df2$int,-c(1:5,13)]<-0`: assuming that you don't want to delete first five cols and last col

Comment: Somebody in you solution doesn't work, for example in the case of second row of `df1` `E.124` match with `E.124` in the second data frame `df2` but the match put a wrong value in column 5 of `df1` it puts `51885967.7` that belongs to `E.203` in `Total` column from `df2` and the correct value should be `71061061.0` that belongs to `E.124` in data frame `df2`. I don't know why the values are wrong @Metrics

Comment: Oops: Are you looking only for matched one?Is it okay to have output with only matched and then non-matched to be NA? If you try `df1[,5]<-df2[match(df1$int,df2$int),13]` then unmatched will be assigned NA

Comment: Please see my update, it is okay with slight change on the rhs of the code.