# string match all possible variable combinations and output new data frame containing 2 new variables: combination count and strings matched

Tags: r

Have a data frame as described here:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
String <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f')

id_data <- data.frame(ID, String)
```

Which produces:

```
ID  String
1     a
1     b
1     c
1     d
2     a
2     c
2     d
2     e
3     b
3     d
3     e
3     f
```

Trying to compare all possible ID combinations to find count of 'String' that matches by 'ID'.  Desired output is a data frame that includes four variables:
1) 'ID' variable indicating the variables tested

2)  'Count' variable indicating the number of strings matched for a given ID pair

2) 'Matched' variable containing strings that match for that particular variable combination, separated by commas.

3)  'Unmatched' variable containing strings that do not match for that particular ID combination (also comma separated).

Desired output:

```
 ID  Count   Matched   Unmatched
1-2    3     a, c, d      e
1-3    2     b, d         a, e
2-3    2     d, e         a, c, f
```

I've referenced the following, but haven't found a solution to fulfill the above:

[Matching R Data Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624622/match-two-data-frames-in-r-considering-two-variables-and-not-change-the-rows-not)

[combn solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161942/r-create-data-frame-with-all-possible-options-and-number-of-variable-combinatio)

Duplicate and self ID combos can be included in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind,
        combn(
            x = unique(id_data$ID),
            m = 2,
            FUN = function(x) {
                temp = id_data[id_data$ID %in% x, ]
                temp2 = Reduce(intersect, split(temp$String, temp$ID))
                data.frame(
                    ID = paste(x, collapse = "-"),
                    Count = length(temp2),
                    Matched = toString(temp2),
                    Unmatched = toString(setdiff(temp$String, temp2)))
            },
            simplify = FALSE
        ))
#    ID Count Matched  Unmatched
# 1 1-2     3 a, c, d       b, e
# 2 1-3     2    b, d a, c, e, f
# 3 2-3     2    d, e a, c, b, f
```

Comment: You can save a little work if you store the result of `split`. If you `unname` it, you can use `do.call` instead of `Reduce`, as it will always be the same length as `m`.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks, d.b.  Works on a relatively small data set, but having issues scaling.  I may try 'segmenting' the program to see if that helps (open to suggestions).